# why $gte and $lte do not work with a specific date like "2020/12/09" to get a documents like ISODate("2020-12-09T04:32:37.266Z")

Tags: mongodb

what am I doing wrong? I am trying to filter the docs where the date matches: `2020/12/09`

```
let date= "2020/12/09";
let startDate = new Date(new Date(date).setHours(00, 00, 00));  // output: 2020-12-09T05:00:00.000Z
let endDate = new Date(new Date(date).setHours(23, 59, 59, 999));  //output: 2020-12-10T04:59:59.999Z

let filter= {
  mydate: {
    $gte: startDate,
    $lte: endDate,
  },
};

collection:
[{ "mydate":ISODate("2020-12-09T04:32:37.266Z")}]


collection.aggregate(
 [
  {
    $match: filter
  }
 ]
)
```

no matches found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue. I think the issue is with the date string format.

```js
new Date('2020/12/09') --> 2020-12-08T16:00:00.000Z
new Date('2020-12-09') --> 2020-12-09T00:00:00.000Z
```

I resolved the issue by changing the date string format to yyyy-mm-dd and used `setUTCHours` method instead of `setHours` since I need the UTC time,

```js
let date = '2020-12-09'
let startDate = new Date(new Date(date).setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0)); --> 2020-12-09T00:00:00.000Z
let endDate = new Date(new Date(date).setUTCHours(23, 59, 59, 999)); --> 2020-12-09T23:59:59.999Z
```